# How to copy a remote image(without file type extension) using curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have this code working fine with the images that having file extension.

```
$ch = curl_init($remoteImageUrl);
$outputImagePath = dirname(__FILE__)."/saveto/thumbnail.jpg";

$fp = fopen($outputImagePath, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

But this code does not work when $remoteImageUrl has no file extension. It creates an image which is 0 bytes. What is the way to solve the problem?

Comment: file extension is just a naming thing. The problem is somewhere else, probably in the way the server handles your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `FOLLOWLOCATION` when dealing with extension-less files as some servers may get confused. Use the `RETURNTRANSFER` constant to retrieve the image contents as string.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```